# "Vaz Chatasee"......... 

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, sin, midrash

The Medresh says that Moshe said to Hashem "Vaz Chatasee" with the word Az I have sinned and with the word Az I will say Shirah to you. What does the Medresh means when it says Moshe said with the word Az I have sinned to you and with the word Az I will say Shirah to you It a little bit odd.

Comment: This question is hard to read. If you clean it up, it will be more likely to get good answers. Also, please try to use existing tags, if possible.

Comment: Where does Moshe say "V'az Chatasee"? can you add a source?

Answer (score 2):

The midrash is referring to two occurences of the word אז (Az, "then"). In the first, Moshe supposedly sins to G-d:

[Exodus 5:23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0205.htm):
 וּמֵ**אָז** בָּאתִי אֶל-פַּרְעֹה, לְדַבֵּר בִּשְׁמֶךָ, הֵרַע, לָעָם הַזֶּה; וְהַצֵּל לֹא-הִצַּלְתָּ, אֶת-עַמֶּךָ.

"For since I came to Pharaoh to speak in thy name, he hath done evil to this people; neither hast thou delivered thy people at all."

and in the second he praises (says Shira):

[Exodus 15:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0215.htm):
 **אָז** יָשִׁיר-מֹשֶׁה וּבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת-הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת ...‏